# Largest class of real world probability models admitting explicit risk-neutral change of measure

Tags: stochastic-calculus, risk-neutral-measure, real-world-measure

Assume we have two assets, a random asset $A_t$ and deterministic risk-free bond $B_t = e^{rt}$. Let $P$ be a model of the real-world probabilities of $S$ and $Q$ the unique associated risk-neutral measure associated to the numeraire $B$ under the no arbitrage assumption.

If $P$ is determined via $A$ solving the SDE $dA = \mu A dt + \sigma A dW$ then $Q$ can be computed explicitly from $P$ via $dQ = \mathcal{E}(-\int_0^{\cdot} \frac{\mu-r}{\sigma} dW)dP$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is the Doleans-Dade exponential.

The main tools in the proof of this are Girsanov's theorem, which not SDE-specific (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem#Statement) and proving the "demeaned" process is a martingale (via Levy's characterization of Brownian motion).

**Question 1**
$\mu$, $\sigma$, and $r$ are the parameters of the model of the system ($S$, $B$). Can $Q$ be computed directly from $P$ and $S$ without first explictly parameterizing $P$ (eq. $S$) through $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $r$?

**Question 2**
When $A$ is a semimartingale, such as when $A$ solves an SDE, can we still obtain an explicit change of measure?

**Question 3**
What is the largest class of real-world measures for which we can compute $Q$ explicitly in terms of $P$?

Comment: For question 2, how explicit is "explicit change of measure"? For a càdlàg semi-martingale $X$, the Doléans-Dade exponential has a formula in terms of $X$, the continuous part of its quadratic variation, and its jumps, see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential#General_formula_and_special_cases).

Comment: @Shiva I mean explicit. We know under very mild assumptions that $dQ = \mathcal{E}(X)dP$ for some process $X$. I want to know how to describe $X$ completely in terms of $P$. For the SDE case, we use the parameters of the SDE to describe $X = -\int_0^{\cdot} \frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}$.